# Установить background через код

Tags: java, android

Есть путь к изображению, которое находится в папке с приложением. Можно ли как то изменить background указав путь к этому изображению?

Изображение сохранял следующим образом, если это важно

```
private void saveImageToStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage) throws IOException {

    // путь /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
    File directory = requireContext().getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Создаем imageDir
    File mypath = new File(directory,"profile.jpg");

    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath)) {
        // Используем метод сжатия BitMap объекта для записи в OutputStream
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    sharedPreferences.edit().putString(PREF_IMAGE, directory.getAbsolutePath()).apply();
}
```

Comment: setImageUri() ?

Comment: @Style-7
Не понимаю.
Следующий код не работает.
testImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_IMAGE,"")));

Comment: Uri должен быть доступный, изображение не слишком большим